# Getting vectors out of ggplot2

Tags: r, data-modeling, ggplot2

I am trying to show that there is a wierd "bump" in some data I am analysing (it is to do with market share. My code is here:-

```
qplot(Share, Rate, data = Dataset3, geom=c("point", "smooth"))
```

(I appreciate that this is not very useful code without the dataset).

Is there anyway that I can get the numeric vector used to generate the smoothed line out of R? I just need that layer to try to fit a model to the smoothed data.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Well done for providing code.  If you need some toy data to make your example work, remember that R has lots of datasets built -in, that everyone will have access to.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Nice first question.  As @RichieCotton says, you can always use built-in datasets to illustrate the problem.  See my answer for an example of using the built-in dataset `cars`.  See `?cars` for detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is.  ggplot uses the function `loess` as the default smoother in `geom_smooth`.  this means you can use `loess` directly to estimate your smoothing parameters.

Here is an example, adapted from `?loess` :

```
qplot(speed, dist, data=cars, geom="smooth")
```

[image]

Use `loess` to estimate the smoothed data, and `predict` for the estimated values::

```
cars.lo <- loess(dist ~ speed, cars)
pc <- predict(cars.lo, data.frame(speed = seq(4, 25, 1)), se = TRUE)
```

The estimates are now in `pc$fit` and the standard error in `pc$fit.se`.  The following bit of code extraxts the fitted values into a data.frame and then plots it using `ggplot` :

```
pc_df <- data.frame(
    x=4:25,
    fit=pc$fit)

ggplot(pc_df, aes(x=x, y=fit)) + geom_line()
```

[image]